# Excel: Cell Value as Excel Document Metadata Property

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, metadata, documents, properties

I know you can add custom Document Properties in Excel 2007.
see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA100475241033.aspx#5

But I thought there was a way to pull a value from a cell as a custom metadata property 
without code. Maybe I'm searching for it with the wrong terminology. Maybe it has to be done as a Named Range. I know this can be done. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed explanation about how I got around this:

In Excel:

1. Select a cell to be the exported metadata property
2. Change the cell’s Name Box (found to the left of the formula bar) to a name you can reference later (this value does not have to match any column in the SharePoint library)
3. Go to File > Info > Properties > Advanced Properties > Custom
4. Check the box Link to content and the cell that you named should appear as the Source
5. Fill in the Name box to a value that will match a column name in a SharePoint library where the excel file will be published

In SharePoint:

1. Create a column in a document library that will match the property name created in the Custom tab (make sure to specify if the imported cell value will be text/number/etc.)
2. Upload document (the actual document needs to be closed)
3. There should be an extra column containing the cell value

Comment: if the user enters a value in the document information panel *and* the cell, which wins?

Answer (score 0):

I just used the Named Range for the value on the new metadata type.  Then I made sure the same field was in the Sharepoint Library I was publishing to.
Hope this helps!